# undefined method find_all_by_full_profile_id for Class in linkedin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I write app which will give all my data from LinkedIn. I did all but I have this error line:

```
undefined method `find_all_by_full_profile_id' for #<Class:0x007f4779a08008>
```

what this means and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic finders are no longer available in the most recent versions of ActiveRecord. Simply use

```
Model.where(full_profile_id: value)
```

where `Model` is the model name, and `value` is the value of the `full_profile_id` attribute.